# Set of values of $x$ for which $1+\log x<x$

Tags: derivatives, inequality, logarithms

> Find the set of values of $x$ for which $$1+\log x<x$$

$$
x>0\\
f(x)=\log x+1-x<0\\
f(1)=0\\
f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}-1\\
x>1\implies f'(x)<0\\
0<x<1\implies f'(x)>0\\
\implies x\in(1,\infty)
$$
But, my reference gives the solution $x\in(0,1)\cup(1,\infty)$, why am I missing the additional domain ?

Comment: Only your final conclusion is wrong: $f$ is strictly increasing on $(0, 1)$ so $f(x) < f(1) = 0$ for $0 < x < 1$.

Comment: @MartinR ohh I got messed up thinking, since $f$ is increasing in $(0,1)$, it is greater than $f(1)$. I cant believe i was imagining it in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conclusion reached in the last line is wrong. You need to find the values of $x$ for which $f(x)<0$, but you found the ones for which $f'(x)<0$ instead. For the answer, note that $x=1$ is the point of global maximum of $f(x)$ and $f(1)=0$. The function is strictly increasing for $x<1$ and strictly decreasing for $x>1$. This means $f(x)<0$ for all $x>0,x\ne1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac1x<1\iff x>1.$$

Hence by integration,

$$x>1\iff\int_1^x\frac{d\color{green}x}{\color{green}x}<\int_1^xd\color{green}x\iff\log x<x-1$$

and

$$x<1\iff\int_x^1\frac{d\color{green}x}{\color{green}x}>\int_x^1d\color{green}x\iff-\log x>1-x.$$

Comment: This is a good answer, but a small issue I have is you should avoid using the same variable for the limits of integration and the variable being integrated, e.g., your $\int_1^x\frac{dx}{x}$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan: of course. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't see any difference from what you had before.

Comment: @JohnOmielan: $x\ne\color{green }x$.

Comment: I think you have made errors in your inequalities and reached the wrong conclusion.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri: you are right, of course. Thanksfor the proofreading.